# Disable Edit option for a List View row in a custom list based on condition in SharePoint?

Tags: list

I Have a list called "Register" it contains a column named as "status".
Now my requirement is once the status is "approved" or" rejected" that particular row shod be disabled ? is there any way to do it either through SharePoint or SharePoint Designer ?

Here is the picture of my list view .
[image]

I tried through Validation settings but i am not able to disable the row.
Itried through Workflow (basic) but still it is enabled. 
Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you mean by "disabled". 
Do you want it to be visible but not editable ?
Do you need to hide it?

I think you need to stop users from further editing the item.

In this case I can think of two options:

1. You can associate an SPD Workflow to the List, which will be kicked on every update. The Workflow will update the Item's Permissions in case your status field is set to Approved or Rejected (not empty). I'm not quite sure if the specific activity is OOTB in SharePoint 2010. (You have to check it). In case it is not you can install the SPD Activities from CodePlex (http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/)
2. You can add a jQuery Script to the page which hides the Edit Button in case your status field is set. In this case, one can easily update the item by constructing the URL manually.

Comment: Yes i want exactly like the way you have said " it should be visible but not editable " I am trying out the workflow function to disable it .

Comment: I have tried a lot with Workflow and still it is enabled.

Comment: i mean it is not enabled

Comment: Do you have any link for this as an example?